# Neo4j CASE given me syntax errors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute a query depending on the contents of three arrays. regions, parishes and districts. Only one of these arrays will have values the other two will be empty. I am trying to use the cypher CASE statement to do this like so:

```
WITH ["8e159860-7e39-4dd1-a17e-57edaecca256","fe26f22b-170f-477c-ae65-9322dd44887d"] AS regions, [] AS parishes,[] AS districts

CASE 
 WHEN regions IS NOT NULL THEN
  UNWIND regions AS region
   MATCH(r:Region {region_id: region})
   MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d)-[]->(p)-[]->(r)
   WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens
WHEN parishes IS NOT NULL THEN
    UNWIND parishes AS parish
    MATCH(p:Parish {parish_id: parish})
    MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d)-[]->(p)
    WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens
WHEN districts IS NOT NULL THEN
    UNWIND districts AS district
    MATCH(d:District {district_id: district})
    MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d)
    WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens
 END AS tokens_collections

 RETURN tokens_collection
```

however I keep getting syntax errors like

Invalid input 'CASE': expected

I guess I am doing this totally wrong. I would appreciate any assistance in restructuring this query to give my the result I am trying to get

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` clause cannot execute, `MATCH` clauses. To perform conditional Cypher execution, you can use `apoc.when` function, like this:

```
WITH ["8e159860-7e39-4dd1-a17e-57edaecca256","fe26f22b-170f-477c-ae65-9322dd44887d"] AS regions, [] AS parishes,[] AS districts
CALL apoc.when(regions IS NOT NULL AND size(regions) <> 0, 'UNWIND regions AS region MATCH(r:Region {region_id: region}) MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d)-[]->(p)-[]->(r) WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens RETURN tokens', 'RETURN [] AS tokens', {regions: regions})
YIELD value WITH value.tokens AS regionTokens, parishes, districts
CALL apoc.when(parishes IS NOT NULL AND size(parishes) <> 0, 'UNWIND parishes AS parish MATCH(p:Parish {parish_id: parish}) MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d)-[]->(p) WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens RETURN tokens', 'RETURN [] AS tokens', {parishes: parishes})
YIELD value WITH value.tokens AS parishTokens, districts, regionTokens
CALL apoc.when(districts IS NOT NULL AND size(districts) <> 0, 'UNWIND districts AS district MATCH(d:District {district_id: district}) MATCH(m:Member)-[]->(s)-[]->(d) WITH COLLECT(m.tokens) AS tokens RETURN tokens','RETURN [] AS tokens',{districts: districts})
YIELD value WITH value.tokens AS districtTokens, parishTokens, regionTokens
RETURN regionTokens + parishTokens + districtTokens AS tokens_collection
```

Here's the link to `apoc.when` [documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc/apoc.when/). Do install apoc plugin before trying it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested answer.  With APOC.WHEN  apparently I have to query each array and produce an empty COLLECTION for the empty arrays. In my use case only one array can contain data, the other arrays must be null so only one query needs to be executed. Is there an option to do this?

Comment: Also, the solution actually produces an error "Type mismatch: expected List<T> but was Map, Node or Relationship (line 16, column 23 (offset: 1102))
"RETURN regionTokens + parishTokens + districtTokens AS tokens_collection"  apparently we aren't allowed to add the results.

Comment: Ohh that's strange. Try returning region tokens, parishTokens, district tokens directly and see if they are lists or something else

Comment: That's what I had to do....using never browser